# Array count is different in two views iPhone

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

I am adding values to array in one class & accessing that array in another class. Here is my code=>

```
abcView.dateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
// fetch data from db &  assign to date
        [abcView.dateArray addObject:date];
        NSLog(@"Count value of dateArray =>%d",[abcView.dateArray count]);
```

Here I am getting result of count as => 3

After that I am trying to access that array in abcViewController.m 's viewDidLoad method as follow

```
NSInteger countVal = [dateArray count];
NSLog(@"dateArray count =>%d",countVal);
```

Here I am getting result of count as => 0

Please help me ... Thanks

Comment: This question can't be answered as asked. I can't know whether these dateArray objects are the same object, and even if they are, whether you're accessing them at the same time(ish) or changing the arrays in between. Also, the first snippet is clearly wrong, since allocating an array and adding one thing to it will not result in a count of 3. Please use the debugger to trace your code to see what's happening, or give much more context in the question, but doing your own debugging on this will probably be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure dateArray isn't nil in the second case.

If the dateArray is a property of the view, then you'd have to go through the view to access it from your view controller.  For example, if you're setting the view of an ABCViewController to an instance of a UIView subclass named ABCView, then your controller code might look something like this:

```
NSInteger countVal = [((ABCView *)self.view).dateArray count];
```